# Can't make virtual environment using virtualenv with python 2.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv

I need a python 2.7 install for some niche lib that runs into errors on 3.8.

So I tried to make a virtual environment using virtualenv using the following command:

`virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe pdf`

This returns the error:

`RuntimeError: failed to query C:\Python27\python.exe with code 1 err: '  File "C:\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv\\discovery\\py_info.py", line 152\n    os.path.join(base_dir, exe) for exe in (f"python{major}", f"python{major}.{minor}")\n                                                           ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n'`

Looks like it wants to find the minor and major release info, but can't. I just installed Python 2.7.0 from [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/). Should I just use a different release instead?

Comment: Okay, first question: Why do you need 2.7? It's been dead for over 3 years. Virtualenv you have was installed for 3.8 (see the path) and it seems it uses syntax from 3.6+ (the error you showed is because of fstrings that were introduced in 3.6). For it to work, you would need a lower version of virtualenv (preferably installed directly with 2.7 interpreter)

Comment: Also, you said you installed 2.7.0 - as the page you linked says "Python 2.7.0 was released on July 3rd, 2010." If you really want 2.7 for some weird reason, at least use newest 2.7 that is also linked on that page ("Note: A bugfix release, 2.7.16, is currently available. Its use is recommended.")

Comment: scientific software has it's own rules. sometimes a dependency on an older lib that has never been updated will lead to silly errors, such as setting the title of a matplotlib window being done by a deprecated command. when your colleague tells you: "Worked for me on python 2.7." You don't really question it and just go ahead with it so that you can finally get to the analysis results that you need for your thesis. But yeah that makes sense. Anyways, I have finally discovered a different way (hopefully) to fix my issue.

Comment: Not really, that's just an excuse. In fact every data scientist would strongly disagree with the very idea. You mean *academic* software that was only used for a single project then abandoned. Now *you* get to fix the inherent problems - either try to rebuild a deprecated environment using possibly discontinued or non-existent libraries, or migrate the old code so it runs on supported Python. `setting the title of a matplotlib window being done by a deprecated command.` yes, because Matplotlib move on since.

Comment: You could look for forks of the original thing that are made for python3. If that's some common piece of software, then it was migrated for sure.

Comment: As for the error you got, pay attention to it. It says `"C:\\Python\\Python38\\lib..`. That means you're running Python 3.8, not Python 2.7. The `virtualenv` command you used runs on the default Python installation, ie 3.8, because that's what was found in the PATH. You'd have to install it in your Python 2.7 folder instead, using a 2.7 version of PIP installed in that environment, to begin with.

Comment: When you installed Python 2.7 the installer *probably* installed shortcuts that open a console window with 2.7 in the path instead of 3.8. Have you tried using that shortcut, to install PIP, virtualenv and anything else you need?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's kinda the other way around, or rather both. virtualenv is installed for 3.8 but has -p flag to select the interpreter. Then it runs some stuff from its own files (hence still \Python38\ in path) using 2.7 - and failing because the file uses newer syntax (fstring specifically, introduced in 3.6). I know how it works because I use virtualenv (or rather virtualenvwrapper) on my own machine, the fact that it allows for more versions is nice because I don't have to reinstall it for each version (I have it since 3.8 but use it with all sorts of versions - from 3.6 to 3.10)

Comment: so what I'm getting from this is that when I quickly installed virtualenv over the command line, it defaulted to installing the virtualenv version for python 3.x, which cannot make python 2.x virtual environments?

Comment: How did you install `virtualenv`? With `pip install virtualenv`? What `pip`? `pip --version`?

Comment: just pip install virtualenv. my default python is python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `virtualenv` for Python 2.7 and use it this way:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install virtualenv
C:\Python27\python.exe -m virtualenv pdf
```